Intersection multiplicity of affine curves at certain point equals algebraic multiplicity of polynomial root
Let $p\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ be a non-constant polynomial and $\beta\in\mathbb{C}$ a root of $p$. If $k$ is the greatest positive integer such that $(x-\beta)^k$ divides $p$, then $k$ equals the intersection multiplicity of the affine curves $y=0, y=p(x)$ at the point $(\beta,0)$.

So far I have:
First, I can write $p$ as $p(x)=(x-\beta)^kg(x)$, and then $p(x+\beta)=x^kg(x+\beta).$
$$I_{(\beta,0)}(y,y-p(x))\\
=I(y,y-p(x+\beta))\; \text{(using reduction mod y)}\\
=I(y,-f(x+\beta))\\
=I(y,x^kg(x+\beta))\; \text{(using union property)}\\
=I(y,x^k)+I(y,g(x+\beta)).$$
Now, $I(y,x^k)=k$, which means that $I(y,g(x+\beta))$ should equal $0$. But I'm stuck when trying to verify that $I(y,g(x+\beta))=0$. Any help is appreciated.
Addendum: The rules of intersection I'm using are the one given to me by my professor, but I'm almost sure he took them from the text Conics and Cubics by Bix.

You've kept subscripting with $_{(\beta,0)}$ even after you've moved to $(0,0)$ - this is a bit confusing and could be causing an error. Anyways, by definition, $g(x)$ doesn't vanish at $\beta$, so $g(x+\beta)$ doesn't vanish at $0$ - do you have a rule covering that case? (It would be good to write all your rules and where they're coming from down in this post with an [edit].)

@KReiser yes, sorry. I forgot to omit the subscript, it's because I copied and pasted the code and after the first line. Will edit the question

@KReiser I have a rule which states: $I(f,h)=0$ if $f$ and $g$ do not intersect at $(0,0)$. This is the one which gives me the desired result, right?

Yep! If you've figured it out, I would suggest writing an answer to your own question.

Consider the rule:
$I_O(f,h)=0$ if $f$ and $h$ do not intersect at $(0,0)$.
Using the fact that $g$ does not intersect $y$ at the origin, then $I(y,g(x+\beta)=0$.
